# AssertJ exception handling (feat.assertThat+isInstanceOf)

Tags: java, junit5, assertj, exceptionhandler

I have been on this problem for hours but couldn't get close to solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public static int enterTheAmount(){
    int final LOTTO_PRICE = 1000;
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(Console.readLine());
    if(amount%LOTTO_PRICE!=0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    return amount/LOTTO_PRICE;
}
```

Here, a user is going to enter a number, and if the number is not divisible by 1000, it throws an exception.

```
void validateTheEnteredAmount(){
    final String INVALID_NUMBER = "1234";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(INVALID_NUMBER.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    assertThat(Application.enterTheAmount()).
            isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class);
}
```

And I want to know when invalid number is entered, illegalArgumentException is thrown.
I used assertThat method & isInstanceOf methods to validate.
but for some reason, the test keeps failing..
Anyone with clues, please help

i used inputStream to store the number into the scanner.
On the console, it shows that illegalargumentexception is thrown, but the test fails..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the same situation I added a variable with `Class` type :

```
private Class exceptionClass;
```

And I will initialize it in a `catch` block as below:

```
public void updateBalance() {
        try {
            Account account = accountRepository.findById(id).get();
            account.setBalance(balance);
            accountRepository.save(account);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionClass = e.getClass();
        } 
    }
```

And I wrote a method for my class that will check the result like below:

```
boolean hasObjectOptimisticLockingFailure() {
    return this.exceptionClass == ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class;
 }
```

Then in my test method I checked it with below assertion statement:

```
assertTrue(account1.hasObjectOptimisticLockingFailure() 
|| account2.hasObjectOptimisticLockingFailure());
```

I think you can do the same for your codes!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `assertThrows` to check this.

```
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> Application.enterTheAmount());
```

This will assert that the method throws an exception. If it doesn't, the test will be considered as failed.

Comment: Thank you!! your answer solved my problem!
it's so hard to decide or even to know what Assertion method to use under difference circumstance. I'll keep digging. 
Once again i appreciate it

Comment: You could also make it more readable

`assertThatExceptionOfType(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> Application.enterTheAmount());`